# Condicionar llamado a datos nulos, de un subselect - transact sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Necesito ver las compras que no tienen asociada un `nombre_etapa`.

Les dejo el código:

```
SELECT
re.[compras] AS compras,
(
SELECT e.[nombre] as nombre_etapa_e
FROM [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Registro_Etapa_Documento] AS e
) as nombre_etapa
FROM [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Requisicion] AS re 
LEFT JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Registro_Etapa_Documento] AS e ON e.[idEtapa] = re.[idEtapa]
WHERE 
e.[nombre] IS NULL
```

Se ve muy simple, pero no sé de que forma traerlo.
Actualmente lo llamo como lo escribí arriba, pero no me trae ningún dato, siendo que si existen compras que no tienen asociada `e.[nombre]`.

Esta query es mucho mas compleja, solo la resumí, el  subselect si es necesario.
El tema es como llamar cuando es un subselect el que trae un dato, desde el `WHERE` principal de la query.

Si quisiera llamar las asociaciones vacías de `re.[compras]` simplemente los llamo con `WHERE re.[compras] IS NULL`. pero cuando hay un `subselect` que trae el dato, no logro ver la forma de traer el dato nulo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la función COALESCE

```
SELECT COALESCE(e.[nombre],"Este dato es nulo") as nombre_etapa_e
FROM [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Registro_Etapa_Documento] AS e
```

Comment: en el `WHERE` de la query principal, en el llamado al dato `IS NULL`, es en donde no tengo la sintaxis, no me sirve el `COALESCE` al parecer,

Answer (score 0):

no entiendo cual es la razón por la cual haces un subselect de la tabla, la única razón por la cual seria pertinente hacer el subselect es si tu tabla tiene muchos campos, pero bueno 
por lo que entiendo quieres hacer la comparación entre dos tablas A y B
y quieres traer los resultados que existen en A pero no existen en B 
es correcto?, si esto es así 
puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera

```
select *
from tablaA A
full outer join tablaB
on a.id = b.id
where b.id is null
```

esto hace un join de tus dos tablas si existe en A y no en B te pone el registro de A y el B te lo deja en nulo y viseversa.
pero como lo estamos filtrando que b sea null
entonces te regresa solo lo que existe en A y en B no existe.

espero haberte podido ayudar y si tienes alguna duda puedes enviarme un mensaje, para ayudarte, saludos!

Comment: El subselect se debe a que el registro A `compra` puede tener más de un registro de `etapa`de la tabla B.

Ejemplo:

Compra    etapa    nombre_etapa.     Registro_doc
Lápiz.
Creo que no me sirve `full outer` ya que el subselect no puede ser de otra forma. O talvez si, pero siempre ligado a la query principal, que es allí en donde debo indicar que los datos a mostrar en la query principal serán solo los que no tengan una etapa de autorización asociada o el resultado de `e.nombre`  sea nulo.